# Git: Duplicate Signed-off-by lines

Tags: git, githooks

I had a new git repository with only two commits, and one push to GitHub. Then I did

```
chmod -R a+x * .*
```

to make all my files executable. I then also removed a file, but when I tried

```
git commit -m "Removing file"
```

I was "Suddenly" greeted with the following error message

```
Duplicate Signed-off-by lines.
```

I have not used the Signed-off-by functionality at all.

Why does this suddenly happen, when the two first commits proceeded without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the following link put me on the right track:

http://willnorris.com/2009/02/git-duplicate-signed-off-by-lines

I realized that there is a bug in the default example hooks file in my local .git folder:

```
.git/hooks/commit-msg
```

So after I ran the following command (to disable that file again) my problem disappeared ü

```
chmod a-x .git/hooks/commit-msg
```

Cheers!